# Are persistent handlers deprecated for search?

Tags: windows, winapi, search

I'm very confused about the status of persistent handlers in Windows for searching.  On the one hand, the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the subject implies at the top of the page that they are unavailable in Windows 8:

> Note  Indexing Service is no longer supported as of Windows XP and is
>   unavailable for use as of Windows 8. Instead, use Windows Search for
>   client side search and Microsoft Search Server Express for server side
>   search.

On the other hand, I have an application whose code I'm looking through that still goes through the registry to find a file extension's persistent handler, load the DLL, and get the info through the `IFilter` interface.  Whatsmore, in Windows Server 2012 (which is the server equivalent of Windows 8), registry keys in the form of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\.docx\CLSID\{PersistentHandlerGUID}\PersistentAddinsRegistered` still exist, and still have values set that point to persistent handlers.  So what's the deal?  Are they deprecated?  Is it just a lie that they are unavailable in Windows 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not deprecated, but they have been renamed to "Filter handlers". When Windows (Desktop) Search was just a standalone add-on it also used the IFilter interfaces present on most machines. Windows Search is now part of Windows and has relieved the Indexing Service of its duty as the system wide "extracted text from files" indexer.

The PersistentHandlerGUID registration documentation under the Windows Search part of MSDN is located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940433(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Interestingly, they seem to have completely renamed them to "Filter handlers", such that a search for "persistent handler" in Google won't lead to that documentation, even though they still have the "PersistentHandler" key in the registry.